Vite.Config base breaks JSON.parse?
Im fetching data from a json to show a list of products.
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('../data/data.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      setProductData(data);      
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {productData.map((item, index) => (
        <Card product={item} key={index}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  )

It works fine until I change the base.
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/test"
})

Then I get this error:
"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
Obs: if I use an empty string it woks (base: "").

Solved it.
Just changed the path to
`${import.meta.env.BASE_URL}data/data.json`

